# How can I redirect to custom pages when a user click New/Edit/Display in a SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, spfx

We are replacing the forms for our lists with forms built with SPFx. Building and deploying the form is no issue. The problem is redirecting the form controls to this form (when a user opens an item or clicks new, etc...). Is there a recommended method of accomplishing this? I have been successful using two methods but they both seem volatile and hacky. 
The first being replacing the entire form code using SharePoint designer. For instance, the new form code would be

```
<%@ Page language="C#" %>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    const list = window.location.href;
    const site = list.substring(0,list.toLowerCase().indexOf('/lists/'));
    window.location.replace(site + "/SitePages/MyListForm.aspx");
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This works sometimes... Upon saving, the form code seems to regenerate the form code but the redirect still works. However, if I open and save the code again, everything breaks and the list action goes back to default (clicking new would now show the 'New Item' call out instead of directing to the form).
The other method is opening the new/edit/display form in the browser, with ?toolpaneview=2 which allows me to add a script web part to the page (although it doesnt like to save) and add the script redirect in.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const list = window.location.href;
    const site = list.substring(0,list.toLowerCase().indexOf('/lists/'));
    window.location.replace(site + "/SitePages/MyListForm.aspx");
</script>
```

this seems to be less volatile than the first method, but it still seems hacky. If I delete the original form web part, the form breaks and the list actions again revert to default. Editing the script requires visiting the form with ?contents=1 to delete the script web part and then I have to re-add it again using the toolpaneview method. In order to even save the web part change I have to click "Edit Web Part", which in turn saves it. There is no simple "Save" action which again makes me feel like this method is not intended to be done. 


Is there any recommended way to accomplish these redirects? I've found plenty or tutorials online about setting up the list form, but nothing about this essential step.

Comment: are you using list/library in classic or modern view? for classic view you can use js link to display a button with every list item that will take you to your edit/display form. for New form you can hide default link using CSS and create similar link using content editor  webpart (ofcourse you can style it using css) which will take user to your new form

Comment: @Seth any news about this? Another way is using contenttype editformurl and new, but it gives problems with some parameters if the page is modern page